# Install PROJ 5 on Linux without compiling

Tags: installation, proj, linux

I would like to try PROJ 5 to understand if it solves some issues with version 4. The [documentation](https://proj4.org/install.html#installation-from-package-management-systems) states the following regarding Linux:

> How to install PROJ on Linux depends on which distribution you are
>   using. Below is a few examples for some of the more common Linux
>   distributions:
>
> On Debian and similar systems (e.g. Ubuntu) the APT package manager is
>   used:
>
> `sudo apt-get install proj-bin`
>
> [...] On Red Hat based system packages are installed with yum:
>
> `sudo yum install proj`

However, only packages for version 4 are available (example from Ubuntu):

```
$ apt policy proj-bin
proj-bin:
  Installed: 4.9.3-2
  Candidate: 4.9.3-2
  Version table:
 *** 4.9.3-2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Is there any other package source out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to Angelos Tzotsos](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2018-November/001789.html), PROJ 5.2 is now available for Ubuntu from the [ubuntugis-experimental](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-experimental) PPA

This is not yet user ready, hiccups are to be expected. But gives at least an opportunity to try the new version in a controlled environment.